# What is the difference between remotely storing data in session or database?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, session, caching

Could you state what is the difference in performance between storing data remotely in dedicated cache/session servers for caching/ session, like Couchbase (which is a different machine) and storing session in the database (which is also a remote server)?

I read somewhere, REST architecture has been introduced to fill the gap, while the session is stored in the server, So rest was not required if we store the session in the database if the database is running on the remote server.

Comment: Related: [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you have an external datastore where you hold session data. Whether this is a relational database or some dedicated cache server doesn't make a difference conceptually (though one approach may be more suitable than the other depending on your requirements and deployment environment).

I'm not 100% sure what you mean with REST architecture having filled a gap (which gap?), but REST is primarily a stateless way of communicating between machines.

If you have state (e.g. a session) you need to store it somewhere. Where that is, again depends on your requirements. If you have a single page webapp for example you could hold session data on the client and you wouldn't need another datastore for it. In general if you can make it work without a session you should strive to do so as session handling complicates things quite a lot when you think about things like failover behaviour and scalability.

Stateless communication makes things a lot easier - this is probably one of the reasons why the REST way of things got so popular.